# Link to blog index from template

Tags: permalinks, templates

I can't believe I did not find the right function for this:
I just want to retrieve the blog index url from a template.

My homepage is a static page. I am not looking for bloginfo('url') because it gives me my root url (/). I am looking for mysite.com/Blog

I am thinking about getting it via get_permalink($mypageid) but it is a bit dirty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are referring to the 'posts page' as set under ***dashboard - settings - reading***:

```
<?php 
if( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) { 
  echo get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ); 
} else { 
  echo home_url(); 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<?php echo home_url(); ?>` <-- Set in Settings > General > WordPress address

`<?php echo site_url(); ?>` <-- Set in Settings > General > Site address

Comment: Hello. Thank you for answering but both snippets you gave link to the site home, not the blog home.

Comment: So set it to whatever you need it to be in your General Settings page.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Blog URL you can use the below code.

```
get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
```

If you are using WordPress 4.5+ then you can use the below code which will work for any post type.

```
get_post_type_archive_link( 'post' );
```